# A cocos2d program with low frame

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I start a iPad game using cocos2d..
When I add a full screen image as its background, the frame decreases to 30..
Is there any way to improve it?
Did iOS Simulator cause this?

```
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"demoBackground.png"];
background.position = CGPointMake(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self addChild:background];
```

Comment: How big is the image; are you sure you add it only once?

Comment: Full screen-1024*768.Only once of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run the app on the real iPad. I had similar issue with images for retina screen. On the simulator it was incredible slow (fps) but on the iPod was very smooth.

Comment: I have also tried to load in the retina display & it gave double FPS than that of simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have always found that FPS on Sim for Cocos projects is much lower than on device. You should never pay attention to FPS on a simulator. Always load your projects on a device. This isn't the only reason why. Consider memory usage. With the Sim, you can load all sorts of stuff, but your app may immediate crash on device because they have much less memory available. In general, test your apps on Device. Those natural Memory Warnings that iOS sends your app's delegate will only occur on Device as well, and it's very good to know when you've hit Level 2 warnings, and you won't see that in Sim (at least I never have).

I only use the Sim for testing general positioning and layout results with my code. I never test performance or interactivity on the Sim.

Answer (score 0):

Are you measuring the framerate of the Simulator? That would render your question moot. Simulator performance is irrelevant and misleading as you're only measuring how fast your Mac can run the Simulator. All of your users will be running your app on a device.

On an actual device, a single fullscreen background image will not drop the framerate. You need to be doing a lot of other things as well to drop the framerate below 60 fps even on a 1st generation iPad.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : It can not be said enough. Could be that the sim does NOT use the GPU of the host, the difference is drastic between sim and just about any device. When doing computationally intensive stuff, sim wins hands down. For graphics, its devices-1 sim-0.